# Apply data validation to many cells based on existing VBA function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I don't know how to run through a string in a loop using just a formula.

This is the vba code that I am trying to convert into a formula. I want to use this formula for data validation of various cells.

**Formula:**

```
Function Test(pValue) As Boolean
    If Len(pValue) < 2 Or Len(pValue) > 99 Then
        AlphaNumeric = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    LPos = 1
    LValid_Values = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.0123456789"
    While LPos <= Len(pValue)
        LChar = Mid(pValue, LPos, 1)
        If InStr(LValid_Values, LChar) = 0 Then
            Test = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        LPos = LPos + 1
    Wend
    Test = True
End Function
```

**The simple part of the formula that I wrote:**

```
=IF(AND(LEN(E4)>1,LEN(E4)<100,____Formula_Here____),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I am assuming that if I select `E4:E50000` and click on `DataValidation`, select `Custom` from the dropdown and then enter the above formula then it will automatically apply it for E4, E5, E6.. E50000 as well. Please do correct me if I am mistaken.

Also, I want this to run on Excel 2003 and higher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fill in the blank with

```
NOT(ISERROR(SUM(SEARCH(MID(E4,ROW($1:$99),1)," ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.0123456789"))))
```

This is an array formula, so you would enter it with ctrl-shift-enter if using in the worksheet. However, the custom formula of the data validation (at least in 2003) automatically treats this as an array formula, so just enter it normally.

Let's break it down from the inside out. `ROW($1:$99)` inside an array formula provides the looping mechanism. It will cause the surrounding array formula to evaluate at each of `i = 1, 2, ..., 99`, so `MID` will take the `i`th character of `E4` in turn. `SEARCH` is case insensitive, so we can omit `a..z` since we have `A..Z`. It returns the position in `A..Z.0..9` where the `i`th character is found or an error otherwise. `SUM` aggregates these positions and will propagate any error. So, if any character is not found, the whole `SUM` will be an error.

Note, as far as I know, you *can* use an UDF in a custom validation formula, so I'm not sure  I follow what your objection is there.

Comment: Nice trick with the ROW Function!  I use the COLUMN function in VLOOKUP array formulas to turn a row of VLOOKUPs into one VLOOKUP formula.  This trick helps me reduce the size of my massive Workbooks and I have been able to use this to do a VLOOKUP across huge ranges, from Column A to XFD.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use your function in the formula: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx

Comment: This method does not work. I can not reference a custom function in the data validation custom field directly. There is a workaround which isn't really worth using as I need to do this data validation on 4 columns and it'll only increase the size of the excel file x2

Answer (score 0):

The idea I had was to use a bunch of nested substitute functions to reduce a valid entry to ""  and do data validation to ensure that that is "".

Here is the nested substitutions.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1," ",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z",""),"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),".",""),"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9","")
```

It turns out that doesn't do you much good because I couldn't copy-paste that into data validation but all is not lost I wrote this in VBA.

```
Sub jf()
Dim lValid_values As String
Dim rowcount As Long
lValid_values = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.0123456789"
Dim form As String
Dim desired_column As String
Dim desired_rowMin As Long
Dim desired_rowMax As Long
Dim InitialCell As String
Dim temp As String
desired_column = "E"
desired_rowMin = 4
desired_rowMax = 50000
InitialCell = desired_column & desired_rowMin
form = "substitute(||cell||," & """" & " " & """" & "," & """" & """" & ")"

Do While lValid_values <> ""
form = "substitute(" & form & "," & """" & Left(lValid_values, 1) & """" & "," & """" & """" & ")"
lValid_values = Right(lValid_values, Len(lValid_values) - 1)
Loop
form = "=AND(LEN(||cell||)>1,LEN(||cell||)<100," & form & "=" & """" & """" & ")"

For rowcount = desired_rowMin To desired_rowMax
temp = Replace(form, "||cell||", desired_column & rowcount)

With Range(desired_column & rowcount).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=temp
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
Next rowcount
End Sub
```

I started to run this going up to 50000 but its pretty slow so I stopped it at around 4000.  It does work so hopefully it isn't something you have to do more than once.  You do have to change what the desired_column, desired_rowmin, and desired_rowmax variables are to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found of doing this was to use a helper column.

Assuming you have your data in `E4:E50000`

F4 would be `=Test(E4)`
copy this value down to the end, so you now have your helper column (if you want to check, last one would be `=Test(E50000)` )

The data validation custom formula would then be `=F4` (when you enter this with your range E4:E50000 selected, it will copy it down, and adjust the reference to point to the corresponding cell next to it).

You also have an error in your code - you have `AlphaNumeric = False`, when it should be `Test = False`. Setting **Option Explicit** would help find these errors.

---

The slightly modified version of your routine I used in my test spreadsheet:

```
Option Explicit

Function Test(pValue) As Boolean
Dim lPos As Long
Dim lValid_Values As String
Dim LChar As String

If Len(pValue) < 2 Or Len(pValue) > 99 Then
    Test = False
    Exit Function
End If
lPos = 1
lValid_Values = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.0123456789"
While lPos <= Len(pValue)
    LChar = Mid(pValue, lPos, 1)
    If InStr(lValid_Values, LChar) = 0 Then
        Test = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    lPos = lPos + 1
Wend
Test = True
End Function
```